# Navigate to specific slide in Powerpoint saved as html in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have a Powerpoint file saved as html and it is inserted into a Page Viewer WebPart in Sharepoint 2010. It is working well but I cannot work out how to display a specific slide.

The URL for the Powerpoint is:
http://xxx.yyy.com.au/Documents/PPName_files/frame.htm

I can see you can naivigate to a specific slide from within the frame using javascript:
javascript:GoToSld('slide0123.htm');

Is there someway to combine these in the URL to open the presentation at a specific slide number?

Sorry but I do not know much about javascript.

Thanks,
janie